# Cannot make an if statement with a public variable. (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am currently trying to create a script in adobe animate, that would make a certain animation play inside a symbol, when a public variable named "kill" would reach 1. The variable would've been increased, when a separate button was pressed. This was working fine, until I started to make an if statement inside that symbol. This if statement was:

```
if (kill == 1);
{
    play();
}
```

When I go to test this movie, it comes out with "Error 1176". I am still very new to AS3, so I do not know what that is. If anybody knows a solution, please help!

P.S A previous error message told me to write:

```
var kill = 1;
```

in a seperate event. Just saying if that could be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the complete code I'm just guessing here but I see 2 issues with the code you have posted.

Firstly you have a semi colon at the end of your if statement, it should read:

```
if (kill == 1)
{
    play();
}
```

Secondly, remove the `var` in your event handler. `var kill` will define a new local variable in the scope of your event handler and won't change the state of your global variable. I'm assuming you have defined the `kill` variable somewhere at the top level of your script, so in your handler you should just reference it directly i.e.:

```
kill = 1;
```